# Angular 8 HttpClient Post Request Content-Type debacle

Tags: angular, post, httpclient, content-type, angular8

I'm not sure what the deal is, hopefully someone can give me some help!

I'm trying to make a POST to the backend API, but I get a 415 status code because the content-type is being sent as "text/plain" but this endpoint is expecting application/json.  I thought maybe it was the API, but the POST works just fine in PostMan (see screenshot below).

I've tried to manually set the content-type to application/json in the request headers, but I just get a 500 status code (see screenshot below).  All other endpoints of the API are working just fine, but they're expecting "text/plain"...any help is greatly appreciated!

I just setup a simple button to make the POST:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.less']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {}

onClickMe( ) {

    // I'VE TRIED ALL THESE DIFFERENT WAYS ALSO

      /* 
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

        const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        const options = {
            headers: httpHeaders
        }; 
      */

    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set(
        'Content-Type',
        'application/json'
    );
    const uNameObj = {
        username: "asdf"
    };

    const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(uNameObj);
    let existsCheck: boolean;
    this.http
      .post('http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/username',
            '{"username": "asdf"}',
           {
             observe: 'response',
             headers: httpHeaders
            })
       .subscribe(
           responseData => {
               if (responseData.status === 200) {
                   existsCheck = true;
               } else {
                   existsCheck = false;
               }
           },
           error => {
               console.log('Error with post button', existsCheck);
           }
       );
    }
 }
```

[image: NO HEADER OPTIONS ADDED]
[image: WITH CONTENT_TYPE CHANGED IN HEADERS]

[image: POSTMAN SCREENSHOT - 200 STATUS CODE:]
[image: BACKEND API CORS FILTERS]

Comment: have you tried: `this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/username',
           jsonStr,` and how your Post Action Method looks like?

Comment: Yeah I tried that.  Sorry, I meant to state that.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request use an interface and post uNameObj

Comment: Hey Andrew, I'm not really sure what you're suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for your specific case, you don't really need to do anything extra to set the request `Content-Type` as `application/json`. That's something that `HttpClient` does for you out of the box [for most of the cases](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f6e15b93897a5b391ab293215f5a570b19559987/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L269).

Now as far as your error is concerned, that has something to do with CORS. Since this is an AJAX Request you're making for an API running on a separate PORT(8080) while your Frontend Application is running on a separate port(4200 most probably), the browser would block the request.

To allow, it would need `access-control-allow-origin: *` in the response headers. This is something that your browser would do by sending an `OPTIONS` call to the API first.

Since the API doesn't really have `access-control-allow-origin: *` in the response header, it would be blocked. That's exactly what's happening here.

### **FIX:**

Since this is a POST API and you're running the server on the local, it's safe to assume that you can configure the REST API server to enable CORS.

If it were an express server you could enable CORS on it using the [**`cors`**](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) middleware.

> Here's a [**Frontend - Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cors-post?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.
>
> Here's a [**Backend - CodeSandbox Sample**](https://codesandbox.io/s/express-server-with-cors-ns5o2) for your ref.

Comment: Hi @siddAjmera that's part of the thing, the CORS are fine.  The PostMan request goes through just fine and I'm able to hit different endpoints that are set as text/plain, it's just this and another endpoint that are set to application/json that I have issues with.  If you look at the first error screenshot it seems to be going through as text/plain for the content-type

Comment: The API is a Java using Grizzly backend.

Comment: I added an additional screenshot showing the CORS in the API

Comment: @NoobCoderChick Postman is dev tool and so won’t trigger any cors issue you may have on your backend. The fact you don’t get error for text/plain points to cors as this type is not covered by cors. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: @NoobCoderChick, if CORS is not the issue and you're sending those headers from your backend, did you try the code that I've shared in the Frontend - Sample StackBlitz? There's really no need to do anything out of the box to send the request headers as `application/json`. BTW, you're trying to stringify the request body. That's not required. Just send it as a JSON Object the way I've done in the Sample StackBlitz. It should be good. Please do let me know if you're still facing an issue.

Comment: Hi @SiddAjmera yup, I’ve tried both ways.  With and without the headers.  I did try hoe you suggested as well, still getting the same error back.  The weird part is it works just fine with Postman

Comment: The json stringify is only there because I’ve been trying everything lol

Comment: Strange! Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: This is the error I get on the console – "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/username' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Which doesn't make sense because the CORS policies are all set to "*" and I got no probs hitting other endpoints and Postman works just fine

Comment: CORS is only a browser based policy. So called on *only* the browser would be blocked. And the error confirmed that there's an issue with CORS. But you're saying it is enabled from the backend. In which case, nothing really makes sense. Is there a way you can replicate this issue? Probably on a sample stackblitz and share it across?

Comment: Oops, I missed that you replied again.  Yeah let me try to do that.  I completely agree with you.  Especially now that I know that I do not need to change the headers for json to be sent.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I accepted your answer, because it is basically the correct response.  I figured I'd let you know how I fixe it in case you care haha.  I'm not sure why, but my API (Java/Jersey2) was doing something funky when I sent a JSON object.  So I now send a json string from the client and let my API consume the string and convert it to a json object I can then use.  I'm still not sure why Postman would allow it to work, but something with the browser caused a preflight cors error....Anyways, thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Not quite sure how that works. Anyways. I'm glad you found the issue. I hope I was helpful to some extent. :)

Comment: @SiddAjmera I haven't used angular in a while, but If my memory serves me right  I recall that we used to have to set the request `Content-Type` to `application/json`. When did it change?

Comment: @eddy, check [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f6e15b93897a5b391ab293215f5a570b19559987/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L269) out  I've updated the answer to make it more clear based on the context  Hope that helps.